# No release file error ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 22.04

How can I resolve that issue when I'm trying to update:

````
Ign:2 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:3 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease         
Ign:4 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease         
Ign:5 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease       
Hit:6 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Ign:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease           
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:3 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:1 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:3 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:1 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not resolve 'br.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'br.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'br.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'br.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://br.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'br.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```
````

Comment: The current release should not use `old-releases` repo sources. Better restore your sources to default.

Comment: *jammy* won't be found at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ until May 2032, and there are no country mirrors (ie. *br.* is invalid) for old-releases.ubuntu.com. Undo the change you made that cause your sources to point there.

Comment: There is no need to manually edit the sources list to update from 20.04 to 22.04. Use the `do-release-upgrade` method.